# jmeter record and play back

Tags: open-source, jmeter, performance-testing

Can we record and playback web applications using jmeter like doing in selenium/QTP(want to test live server not using localhost)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

yes you can.  http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf
this will give you a good idea.

Comment: just 2 sec gap in answering... :P

Comment: @HarryJoy Thanks for your information . I am using jmeter 2.7 , i followed the instructions available in pdf , i am getting below error message "jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: Problem with SSL certificate? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca"

Answer (score 1):

You may **use HTTP Proxy Server** available in Workbench Non Test Elements to perform recording. You need to follow only below three steps:

1. Add HTTP Proxy with any port of localhost which is not being use.

2. Configure your default browser LAN settings to use localhost with port specified in above step, to be used as proxy.
3. Click on Start in JMETER Http Proxy Server followed by actions to be recorded in any browser of your choice.

You can follow this **link** http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf  for more details as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we record and playback web applications using jmeter?

Yes. See [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) and [here](http://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/jmeter-101-using-http-proxy-to-record-your-test/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try Badboy? You can download the software here:
http://www.badboy.com.au/

Here is the HOWTO document:
http://www.badboysoftware.biz/docs/jmeter.htm